# Adding ActionListener to JButton on JPanel nested in another package

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to gain access to the JButtons on a JPanel in my view. My view class is in a package called project. It essentially is a JFrame with a few JPanels from a package called views. When I utilize view in my controller class, I can gain access to the panels, but I can't go any lower to get the buttons. I tried changing one of the buttons to public, and I still could not gain access to it. Also I have a getter function, but that does not give me access either. I have included the code and project structure below.

Project structure

```
Project
  > src
    > project
        > View.java
        > Controller.java
    > views
        > JButtonPanel.java
```

project/View.java

```
package project;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import config.Config;
import views.JButtonPanel;
import views.JColorPanel;
import views.JImagePanel;
import views.JMaskPanel;

public class View {
    protected JFrame jf;
    protected JPanel jButtonPanel;
    protected JPanel jImagePanel;
    protected JPanel jMaskPanel;
    protected JPanel jColorPanel;

    View() {
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

        this.jf = new JFrame();
        this.jf.setTitle("Gradient coloring app");
        this.jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Config.screenSize.width, Config.screenSize.height));
        this.jf.setLayout(bl);

        this.jButtonPanel = new JButtonPanel();
        this.jImagePanel = new JImagePanel(null);
        this.jColorPanel = new JColorPanel();
        this.jMaskPanel = new JMaskPanel();

        this.jf.add(this.jButtonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        this.jf.add(this.jImagePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        this.jf.add(this.jColorPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        this.jf.add(this.jMaskPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        this.jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.jf.setResizable(false);
        this.jf.pack();
        this.jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return the jButtonPanel
     */
    public JPanel getjButtonPanel() {
        return jButtonPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jImagePanel
     */
    public JPanel getjImagePanel() {
        return jImagePanel;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jMaskPanel
     */
    public JPanel getjMaskPanel() {
        return jMaskPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @return the jColorPanel
     */
    public JPanel getjColorPanel() {
        return jColorPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @param jButtonPanel the jButtonPanel to set
     */
    public void setjButtonPanel(JPanel jButtonPanel) {
        this.jButtonPanel = jButtonPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @param jImagePanel the jImagePanel to set
     */
    public void setjImagePanel(JPanel jImagePanel) {
        this.jImagePanel = jImagePanel;
    }

    /**
     * @param jMaskPanel the jMaskPanel to set
     */
    public void setjMaskPanel(JPanel jMaskPanel) {
        this.jMaskPanel = jMaskPanel;
    }

    /**
     * @param jColorPanel the jColorPanel to set
     */
    public void setjColorPanel(JPanel jColorPanel) {
        this.jColorPanel = jColorPanel;
    }
}
```

views/JButtonPanel.java

```
package views;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import config.Config;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JButtonPanel extends JPanel {

    protected JButton targetButton;
    protected JButton colorSource;
    protected JButton calGrad;
    protected JButton addColorsToGradient;

    public JButtonPanel() {
        FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Config.screenSize.width, (int) (Config.screenSize.height * 0.075)));
        this.setBorder(Config.buttonPanelBorder);
        this.setLayout(fl);

        this.targetButton = new JButton();
        this.targetButton.setText("Load a target image");
        this.add(this.targetButton);
        ...
    }

    /**
     * @return the targetButton
     */
    public JButton getTargetButton() {
        return targetButton;
    }
    ...
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The question is "why" do you want to?  You should be using a model to control the states of the buttons, which should be able to update themselves when the model changes (via the use of an observer pattern)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Don't extend components without good reason. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referring to your custom panel as a JPanel, instead of your custom JButtonPanel:

```
... 

public class View {
protected JFrame jf;
protected JPanel jButtonPanel;
protected JPanel jImagePanel;
protected JPanel jMaskPanel;
protected JPanel jColorPanel;

View() { ...
```

Then it's normal you don't have access to the buttons defined in your Custom JPanel extension, because you are declaring it as a standard JPanel, which, in fact does not have a `getTargetButton()` method.

To solve you have two options:

1. Declare jButtonPanel as `protected JButtonPanel jButtonPanel`
2. Cast jButtonPanel to JButtonPanel (better if checking with instanceof that it's effectively a JButtonPanel object) when you need to access its fields.

If you don't plan to replace jButtonPanel implementation in the future, i suggest you to go with first option.

Alessio